# Docker Drupal 8: ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

Tags: docker, drupal

I already followed different stackoverflow post, but still getting this issue. I am running Drupal 8 and moving project to Docker.

So on root I have created `docker-compose.yml` I have created file & below is my content

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: drupal-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    restart: always
  drupal:
    image: drupal:latest
    container_name: drupal
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./drupal:/drupal
    restart: always
volumes:
  db_data:
```

While running `docker-compose up -d --build` it gives

> Building drupal
>
> ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of the `drupal` service `build: .` is telling docker compose that the relative `Dockerfile` should be in the same directory where `docker-compose.yml` is.

Make sure the path is correct or change it accordingly, the path is relative to the docker file location.

Please, check the compose file [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) and [context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#context) sections for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove build command (which is after depends_on) from your drupal service section of docker-compose file.
Since you are already providing image, you need not build it. So you can just run docker-compose up without --build arg.

If you need to build 'drupal' service then you need to provide build information with (buildContext as current directory in most cases and dockerfile).